# Variational Inequalities and Convex functions

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, gradient-descent, variational-analysis

I am having troubles in understanding the proof of the following proposition.

**Proposition** If $f(x)$ is a convex function and $x^*$ is a solution to VI($\nabla f$,$K$), then $x^*$ is a solution to the optimization problem

$$\min f(x), \text{ subject to: } x \in K.$$

Where VI=Variational Inequality problem and $K$ is a convex set.

**Proof** Since $f(x)$ is convex, 
$$f(x)\geq f(x^*)+\langle \nabla f(x^*)^T,x-x^*\rangle, \quad \forall x \in K.$$

[...]

I do not understand this first step in the proof.

Comment: Look at proposition 4 [here](https://wiki.math.ntnu.no/_media/tma4180/2016v/note2.pdf). It follows from the definition of convex functions.

Comment: Thank you very much @ShikharJaiswal